# How to get hostname from IP using consuls DNS

Tags: linux, networking, dns, dnsmasq, hadoop

I have consul cluster with different microservices serving..., 5 out of them are also part of hadoop cluster...

We have kerberos authentication in hadoop. All the cluster nodes are authenicated via ipa and it uses domain name `.ipaplatform.com` . We also have consul installed in it which uses domain name `.consulplatform.com` . So one node will have two domain names and two hostnames `node10.ipaplatform.com` and `postgres.consulplatform.com`.

In this cluster in case of service failure, using automations new node is launched with unique number in its hostname for example `node-5.ipaplatform.com`(output of `hostname -f`) is hadoop namenode and it fails dut to other service running in same container. In this case we have to modify all the hadoop nodes manually /etc/hosts file to modify fqdns as well as hadoop configs to point it to proper namenode.

So we want to use generic fqdns for our cluster for example. `master.consulplatform.com`, `nodeX.consulplatform.com` and we will add services to consul for the same, lets say node10 is being launched and it was master node of hadoop then we will add `master.consulplatform.com` service. So that we have same hadoop config file irrespective of new node has been launched. Consul will point it to correct master of hadoop irrespective of unique numbered hostname. It is working file as only one node is having namenode.

In case of datanode, earlier we had set `dfs.datanode.kerberos.principal : dn/_HOST@REALM` so it can take hostname correctly at run time, But as nodes also have `ipaplatform.com` domain it uses that hostname. But now in a move to generic fqdn we througt to make it `dn/hadoop-<nodeno>@REALM`. But only datanode which is registered with kerberos principal mentioned in hdfs file of node which runs namenode, is able to connect to namenode.

SO for example if namenode node has this conf(One node is running namenode as well as datanode both out of five nodes)
namenode: nn/master.consulplatform.com
datanode: dn/node-1.consulplatform.com

Then node with datanode principal dn/node-2.consulplatform.com is not able to connect namenode. Namenode shows that only dn/node-1.consulplatform.com  is allowed to connect..

SO we can not keep hadoop confs like that so ultimately we have to use _HOST, but as said earlier it keeps changing so we cant keep it like this also.

So we were thinking to use consuls dns server. For reverse dns lookup. So we found out property [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsMultihoming.html) we gave dns server to 127.0.0.1:8600 were consul dns was running.

But it still uses default hostname of platform. So i want to know how to use consuls dns server for reverse dns lookup that ip resolves to only one nodes hostaname with consulplatform domain. so that whenever reverse dns lookup happen or hadoop ask for hostname it returns `node-1.consulplatform.com` instead of `node-10.ipaplatform.com`.

The problem may be from hadoop side in configuration so or may be from consul side. Note we use dig to investigate it for reverse dns lookup but it was not able to find proper hostname of ip we gave ...., we also try to explicitly use consuls dns by providing ip:port to dig bit neither consul dns nor default dns was able to find hostname. It only gives hostname in case it is present in /etc/hosts file.

Any hint is appreciated thanks in advance.